# How to filter data between two entities in core data iOS

Tags: ios, core-data

1. I have two entities one is Product and other one is PriseList.

Now i want to perform filter or search operation between this two entities .

can any one help me.

Comment: Please give more details.

Comment: Hi I have two entities

Comment: 1. Product. 2.priselist there is no relation between them

Comment: Now i want to perform search on both entities at a time

Comment: and collect the out put in to one nsarray

Comment: is any common attribute there in both two entities like productID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot fetch from two entities at a time, instead you should fetch separately and merge.

To fetch filtered items from CoreData, you should use **NSFetchRequest** together with **NSPredicate**.

Write a general method to fetch from any entity applying filters, sorting etc

```
+ (NSArray *)getItemsInEntity : (NSEntityDescription *)entity FilteredByPredicate : (NSPredicate *)predicate sortedBy : (NSArray *)sortDescriptors inContext : (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext{

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *results = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]];

    return results;
}
```

Use the above method to get items in both entities and combine the results

```
NSEntityDescription *productEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSPredicate *productPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"yourProperty = searchValue"];

NSArray *products = [DMDictation getItemsInEntity:productEntity FilteredByPredicate:productPredicate sortedBy:Nil inContext:managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *priceListEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PriceList" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSPredicate *priceListPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"yourProperty = searchValue"];

NSArray *priceLists = [DMDictation getItemsInEntity:priceListEntity FilteredByPredicate:priceListPredicate sortedBy:Nil inContext:managedObjectContext];

NSMutableArray *combinedArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[combinedArray addObjectsFromArray:products];
[combinedArray addObjectsFromArray: priceLists];
```

Comment: how to merge two fetch results

Comment: ThnkaQ it is helpfullto me